# Compile Android Kernel Module from Source

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, android-kernel, vlan

I'm trying to configure an ethernet interface on my phone to use VLAN. My idea is to compile the VLAN module from the kernel source and simply copy it to my phone.

For this, I need to load the [8021q](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r0.81/net/8021q/) module which is not installed on my device (Pixel 3 with Android 10). I already downloaded the [Kernel Source](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels), and executed `make menuconfig`. There I configured that the 8021q functionality should be compiled as a module.
Yet, when I execute the `build/build.sh` script, I get an error message that the directory should be cleaned with `make mrproper`.

Can anybody help me to compile this module? It seems like a rather easy task, but somehow I cannot compile it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The idea, I guess, is to patch whatever source file that provides the default kernel configuration (usually named like *XXX_defconfig*, where *XXX* is a platform name).